# Apply gradle custom jar plugin

Tags: plugins, groovy, gradle

I've created a simple groovy-based plugin for gradle.

in my gradle.build file I have the following:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}
```

Everything works great, I get a build directory and a .jar is generated in the lib folder, I guess this is the standalone plugin.

Now I want to know how to register this new plugin into my gradle instalation, so I can do 
apply plugin: 'myPlugin' I've done the following:

- Droped the plugin into the plugin folder in the installation
- Created the myplugin.properties file and included it in the META-INF folder
- placed the same properties file in the META-INF in the src dir (act of desperation)

Well after every step when I try to apply the plugin I get the error:

- Plugin with id 'myplugin' not found

How can I get this right??

can you state a list of steps that will get my plugin working? (Im new to gradle+groovy)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [chapter 58](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) of the user guide has all the information you need. In summary:

- Put your `myPlugin.properties` inside your project structure, in src/main/resources/META-INF
  /gradle-plugins/
- Build your jar like you usually do
- In the script you wish to use this plugin, add a `buildscript` closure to something like:

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          flatDir dirs: "build/libs"
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath "your.group:your-plugin:1.0.0"
      }
  }
  ```

Or whatever settings for `repositories` and `dependencies` you wish, but you need to use the `classpath` configuration as I've done here. I don't think you can (or should!) add the jar to the plugin dir of Gradle like you did.

**Note:** the flatDir does not resolve transitive dependencies. The same rule for dependency management applies to the buildscript, so you can use a regular maven or ivy repository to deploy your plugin.

Comment: I've tried this, and still got the following error:

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.gradle.mypluginpack:MyPlugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         :test:unspecified

Comment: Well, probably the repository you specified didn't contain your plugin's jar. My `flatDir` was just for the sake of example. The same rule for dependency management applies in the `buildscript` closure.

Comment: It seems to me that this wouldn't work because it wouldn't include dependencies of that plugin

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew The question didn't mention any dependencies of the plugin and I did mention in the previous comment that dependency management applies in the buildscript; flatDir is for the sake of example and wouldn't resolve any dependencies, but you can still use a custom maven/ivy repository to resolve transitive dependencies. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `samples/customPlugin` and `samples/customDistribution` samples in the full Gradle distribution (or on [GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/)). They should have all information that you need.