# Apply gradle custom module plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I created a plugin for gradle with java.I want to test it.

so, I created a another gradle project add I added my plugin as a module.

Now , How can I apply my module as a plugin in `build.gradle` file ?

**My project structure**

[image]

**My plugin**

```
        version '1.0.0'
        id = 'com.hello.first.plugin'
        implementationClass = 'com.hello.first.plugin'
```

Here I saw for applying jar as a plugin in gradle : [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468515/apply-gradle-custom-jar-plugin).

How can I add module as a plugin in build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it a [standalone project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) and publish it, at least to `mavenLocal()`.

Then just add `mavenLocal()` into `buildscript.dependencies` and it should resolve.

A local `flatDir` repository should work, too.

Comment: can you give more details ?